# clustered TimerService on jboss 7.1.1?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

I'm looking for a way to properly cluster a Java EE app that uses timers. by properly cluster i mean i'm looking for the following features:

1. Timer executions should fall back to other cluster nodes. by this i mean that is some EJB on node A created a Timer:
   `timerService.createIntervalTimer(/* every 10 seconds */)`
   and then went offline (crashed) timeout invocations would start firing on node B (some other cluster node on which the same app is deployed)
2. Timers should be accessible across the cluster. by this i mean that if EJB X created a timer running on node A, then the same EJB X (same class, obviously) running on cluster node B could cancel that timer by doing something like 
   `timerService.getTimers().iterator().next().cancel();`
3. Timer executions could be distributed across the cluster - so for example if my timeout method is some long computation that i didnt complete in 10 seconds (when the timer next expires) i'd like the next timeout invocation to happen on some other, not-as-busy node.

obviously this is my ideal set of features, but any pointer in the right direction would be very welcomed.

Comment: something very much like described in this post: https://community.jboss.org/message/649723#649723

Comment: I am looking for the exactly same thing. As far as I understand this is possible using [WildFly 8 (link)](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/creating-clustered-ejb-3-timers). But is it also possible in JBoss AS 7.1.1?